# Reports on Liferay Usage

Tags: liferay

I'm benchmarking some CMS's for future use. I would like to know if with Liferay it's possible to have (extensions or api's) reports of back office usage.

Examples:

- Users that don't create/update content for more than X days?
- Content Areas that don't have new content for more than X days?
- Number of contents waiting approval?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) For the users you could create a listener that is called whenever a content is created, a seperate table with the serviceBuilder could store those and every X days you could read from that table and check which users are missing

b) content areas? in case you mean webContent you can get the modified date, also i think here it would be easier to create a listener (again). If something is changed it saves the changes somewhere and you can check it every X days

c) JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil can bring you all articles and you can check their state, or you create a custom query to just load those with specific states (i.e. `WorkflowConstants.STATUS_PENDING`)